# How to document WSO2 mediation sequences

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

is there any preferred way how to document WSO2 mediation sequences in Enterprise Integrator? For example, if we design the sequence to be reusable (= can be attached to an API or called from other sequences), we would like to document the inputs and outputs of the sequence. So far we didn't find any built-in mechanism for this, just discovered that XML comments disappear from the sequence source files when edited in Enterprise Integrator Tooling.

We are thinking to place a Script mediator as a first one in the sequence. It would be without actual code, but with comments describing the sequence.

Can you perhaps share how you document the mediation sequences?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use WsoDeveloper Studio to manager integrator related projects. Final result is just **car** file. Despite integrator "erase" comments in deployed files, they are still available in sources.  git helps to remember how project is evolved.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you mean the XML comments, the WSO2 IDE really erases all of them when switched to the "Designer" view, so unfortunately it seems to be a very unreliable way of storing comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence has special field for description.
It can be modified in design [screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/YIsUNXL9OPr-3g) and source view.

```
    <sequence>
...
<description>Bla-Bla</description>
</sequence>
```

You don't have to use git to see what is this sequence for.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. What WSO2 product and version are you using? We have Enterprise Integrator 6.2.0, I tried to add the <description> element to the sequence XML source, but when I switched to Design view and back, it disappeared. I think our version of EI doesn't support this element.

Comment: Update: according to this documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Adding+a+Mediation+Sequence, this sequence description seems to be a quite old feature. However, the WSO2 Eclipse plugin does not support this - there is no editable field for description, and even if I put this <description> element to the XML source, it gets erased. Funny :)